# getting a value from async.forEachOf to pass into next step of async.waterfall

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm having a problem trying to get a value from a query inside `async.forEachOf` that runs depending on an if statement, so I can pass that value into the next step of the `async.waterfall`

Here's the code:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        db.query('select id from topics where description = ?',
            [topic], function(err, rows){
                callback(err, rows);
            });
    },
    function(rows, callback) {
        var query = rows[0].id
        db.query('select id, background, viewOrder, description from topics where parent = ? order by viewOrder',
            [query], function(err, rows){
                callback(err, rows);
            });
    },
    function(rows, callback){
        var callbackRows = rows;
        async.forEachOf(callbackRows, function(row, key, callback){
            var topics
            console.log('rows[key].id: ', callbackRows[key].id);
            if (callbackRows[key].background == 0){
                var query = callbackRows[key].id
                db.query('select id, background, viewOrder, description from topics where parent = ? order by viewOrder',
                    [query], function(err, rows){
                        callbackRows[key].subTopics = rows;
                        topics = callBackRows;
                        console.log('rows from async.forEach db query: ', rows);
                        console.log("from inside asnyc.foreach", callbackRows);
                        });
            }
            callback();
        }, function(){
            callback(null, topics);
            console.log('forEachOf callback called');
        });
        // console.log(topics);
    }
], function(err, topics){
   console.log("from end of waterfall: ", topics);
});
```

I've tried to do this a number of ways, and the error I'm currently getting is that topics is not defined at the line `callback(null, topics)` in the `async.forEachOf` section

Too tired to write more at the moment, I'm going to bed. If this needs improvement later, I'll see to it. In the meantime, what I am trying to do is append the results from the query at the end of the `async.forEachOf` to the element in the array of the value returned by the preceding query. From there, I want to send put this in a response object in express, in the concluding callback in the `async.waterfall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third part the callback needs to be invoked once the data query is finished but also in the else part of the if statement to make sure it is always called exactly once.

```
if (callbackRows[key].background == 0){
    var query = callbackRows[key].id
    db.query('select id, background, viewOrder, description from topics where parent = ? order by viewOrder',
        [query], function(err, rows){
            callbackRows[key].subTopics = rows;
            topics = callBackRows;
            console.log('rows from async.forEach db query: ', rows);
            console.log("from inside asnyc.foreach", callbackRows);
            callback();
            });
} else callback();
```

Answer (score 0):

Topics is undefined, because it isn't defined in either that function's scope, or  the parent function's scope. In your code, `topics` is defined inside the iterator function of forEachOf. The solution is to simply define topics in the parent function  e.g.

```
function(rows, callback){
        var callbackRows = rows;
        var topics; // move the definition to here
        async.forEachOf(callbackRows, function(row, key, callback){
```

Comment: I'm still getting undefined with that change

Comment: I'm getting the console log from the concluding callback before the end of `async.forEachOf`. Also, when I try to put the callback trigger for `async.forEachOf` in the if statement, I don't get the console.log of the concluding callback of `async.waterfall`.

Comment: You have this line right here `topics = callBackRows;`, put a `console.log('topics', topics)` right after that line, and see if it has a value at the end of forEachOf execution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `topics`. Just pass `rows` into the callback. i.e. `callback(null, rows);`

Comment: Did you read the code? I need to pass data to the concluding callback from the second callback in the waterfall with data from the third callback query added.

Comment: Of course I read the code. It seems you don't understand that variables in JavaScript are references to objects. In your third waterfall callback `rows`, `callbackRows` and `topics` all reference the same object. Just change `callback(null, topics);` to `callback(null, rows);` and your code should work.

Comment: Wait, I just found a second error in your code. The callback call, that's after the if needs to be inside the db.query callback. And additionally it also needs to be in the else part of said if.

Comment: In the third part, `rows` references the new query, whereas `topics` and `callbackRows` reference the data transferred from the second waterfall callback

Comment: Ah yeah that was the problem - the lack of callback in if else/else. If you want to make a new answer with that I'll accept it right away

Comment: Not in the line `callback(null, topics);`. At that point `rows` still references the data transferred from the second waterfall callback.